# Need to validate user input as an integer

Tags: python, validation, types

I want to add code so that if the user enters anything other than an integer, it prints something out. On the last line where I wrote 
`if guess != int` I want the program to decide if the guess is anything other than a number.

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,100)
guess = 0
guesses = 0

while guess != number:

    guess = int(input("Guess my number between 1 and 100(inclusive):"))
    guesses = guesses + 1

    if guess == number:
        print("Well done! My number is:"number,"You had",guesses,"guesses"
    elif guess < number:
        print ('sorry, my number is higher')
    elif guess > number:
        print ('Sorry, My number is lower')
    if guess != int:
        print ("Enter a Number!!")
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's use good old [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)

> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many other languages such as C.

```
guess = input("Guess my number between 1 and 100(inclusive):")
try:
    guess = int(guess)
except ValueError:
    print ("Enter a Number!!")
else:
    if guess == number:
        print("Well done! My number is:"number,"You had",guesses,"guesses"
    elif guess < number :`
        print ('sorry, my number is higher')
    else:
        print ('Sorry, My number is lower')
```

Comment: I think regex with a base string is a bit cleaner and more Pythonic than a series of error handling and checks.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi regex is a very heavy operation. __str.isdigit()__ may be a better solution

Comment: So something like the condition `sum(map(str.isdigit, guess.strip())) == len(guess)`

Comment: Department of premature optimization strikes again. This check won't be a performance bottleneck ever, so main argument be readability. And arguably `guess.isdigit()` and `try/except` clause are only two possibilities. And I personally like exceptions more (and so does Guido, as my link shows).

Comment: Thanks for your input but your code doesn't have a loop.

Answer (score 0):

After I was kindly warned about raw input always being a string. Perhaps this is what you need

```
guess =int(input("Guess my number between 1 and 100(inclusive):"))
guesses = guesses + 1
try:
    guess = int(guess)
    if guess == number:
     print("Well done! My number is:", number,"You had",guesses,"guesses")
    elif guess < number :
       print ('sorry, my number is higher')
    elif guess > number:
        print ('Sorry, My number is lower')
except:
    print("Enter a number!")
```

Do notice that you don't use `guesses` anywhere, and that this isn't a loop so it will repeat itself only once and that also you never defined what your number is. Perhaps a more complete example would be this:

```
guesses = 0
number = 10

while True:
    try:
        guess =int(input("Guess my number between 1 and 100(inclusive):"))
    except:
        print("Enter a number!")
        continue

    guesses = guesses + 1  

    if guess == number:
     print("Well done! My number is:", number,"You had",guesses,"guesses")
     break
    elif guess < number :
       print ('sorry, my number is higher')
    elif guess > number:
        print ('Sorry, My number is lower')
```

Comment: Except guess will always be a string.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Thanks for the heads up, I completely glossed over his entire question. I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: In your first example you are casting the raw input to an `int` twice

Comment: Well actually it will always be a integer because of the cast. The problem is, that defeats the purpose of error handling. What if you enter you name? You'll get an error when entering input.

Comment: 2 comments: 1. __try/except__ block should be as short as possible. 2. Endless loop with __break__ is better solution

Answer (score 0):

I like @Nsh's answer - it's more common and probably better in practice.  But if you don't like using try-catch statement and a fan of sql...

```
import random

my_number = random.randint(1,100)
your_number = None
counter = 0
While your_number != my_number:
    s = input("Guess my number between 1 and 100(inclusive):")
    counter += 1
    if all(i in '0123456789' for i in s):
        your_number = int(s)
        if my_number == your_number: print 'Well done!'
        else: print 'sorry, my number is {}'.format('higher' if my_number > your_number else 'lower')
```

Enjoy.